# Setting legend location in matplotlib (while using geopandas)

Tags: matplotlib, plot, legend, geopandas

I have tried several different methods to change my plot's legend's position, but none of them have worked. I would like to set the position for example to upper left or upper right.

I have a GeoDataFrame (data_proj) which has polygons in it. I want to plot only one map with those polygons.

I created my plot like this:

```
   p = data_proj.plot(column = "Level3", linewidth=0.03, legend = True)
```

I used these to set the title etc. for the legend:

```
  leg = p.get_legend()
  leg.set_title("Land cover")
  leg.get_frame().set_alpha(0)
```

How can I change the location of the legend?

Comment: It would help to have a [mcve] available in order to give the correct code as solution.

Answer (score 3):

On geopandas master (i.e., a change made subsequent to the current 0.3.0 release), a `legend_kwds` argument was added to the `plot` method. One can then do the following:

```
ax = df.plot(column='values', categorical=True, legend=True, legend_kwds={'loc': 2})
```

Answer (score 1):

In principle setting the legend should work as usual. The `loc` parameter can be used to define the location of the legend.

```
p = data_proj.plot(column = "Level3", linewidth=0.03)

leg = p.legend(loc="upper right")
leg.set_title("Land cover")
leg.get_frame().set_alpha(0)
```